# What is the total possible combinations for an two dice throw.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Why is the number of combinations for two dice throws $6\times6$ which is $36$ but not also ${12}\choose{2}$ divided by two which is $33$?  This corresponds to choosing two elements from the lot which is $6$ possible numbers from every dice, meaning $12$ in total and dividing by two because the lot has every element repeated one time if I understand it right. Can you please explain what is missed in ${{12}\choose{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$ or why my logic is wrong to consider ${{12}\choose{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$ as the answer?

Comment: What are the twelve outcomes you have in mind?

Comment: I want to say that there are 12 elements in the lot because every dice has 6 numbers and you take 2 elements when you throw the dice but evey number of the lot repeats once so i divide by two. Is that wrong?

Comment: Imagine you have 6 girls and 6 boys and also want you have 2 chairs. If you want to sit in the first chair a boy and in the other a girl, there is 6 possible options of boy for every girl you sit, so there are 6 girls, hence 6×6 options.

Comment: It's not $\frac{\binom{12}{2}}{2}$ but $\binom{6}{1}^2$ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say we have two dice labeled $a$ and $b$. The $12$ outcomes are,

$\{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6\}$

You are counting $ \displaystyle {12 \choose 2} = 66$ outcomes. Now for example, out of $ \{a1, a2 \}$ and $ \{a1, b2 \}$, only the latter is valid. But you cannot simply divide by $2$ as there is no $ \{a1, a1\}$ for example. So you first need to subtract $6$ when both numbers are same. That gives you $60$ outcomes and out of that, only $30$ are valid. That leads to $30 + 6 = 36$ outcomes.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail why you have to sustract 6 elements when both numbers are the same and then add them back to get all the outcomes?

Comment: @NegoitaMihai take any two numbers that are different, say $1, 2$. ${12 \choose 2}$ will count $(a1, a2), (a1, b2), (a2, b1), (b1, b2)$ - $4$ count but two of them are valid. But if the numbers are same, say $1, 1$. Then you can only select $(a1, b1)$ - $1$ count and it is valid. If you do not subtract, you will divide this also by $2$ but when it is same numbers, there are no duplicates so we should not divide by $2$.

Comment: The explanation given by MathLover is correct, but it suggests that $6 \times 6$ is not the basic normal formula. You throw your dices ; you look at first dice (the blue one), you have 6 values. Then , you look at the red one. You have also 6 values. Total is 6x6. When you have many dices (or many balls or ...) you should always consider that you can distinguish them (blue dice and red dice ...) ; it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

In using $\frac{_{12}C_2}{2}$ to calculate the number of possible combinations, you assume that each possible dice roll appears twice in the two-element subsets of the 12-element set containing each face twice. This is true for when you roll two different numbers (one die has the higher number, other die has the higher number). But when the two numbers are the same (ie. you roll doubles), they are only counted once, so your assumption is false.

Since the two rolls are independent, it's better to consider the possibilities separately and multiply them together:

$$N=\binom{6}{1}\binom{6}{1}=6\cdot6=36$$

If you wanted, you could calculate the number of possibilities by breaking it down into cases. If you roll doubles, there are clearly $\binom{6}{1}$ ways to do that. If you don't roll doubles, then you have two different faces, with $\binom{6}{2}$ options. Then each of those can be ordered in 2 ways, so:

$$N=2\binom{6}{2}+\binom{6}{1}=2(15)+6=36$$

Answer (score 0):

$(1,1),    (1,2),    (1,3),    (1,4),    (1,5),    (1,6)$

$(2,2),    (2,3),    (2,4),    (2,5),    (2,6)$

$(3,3),    (3,4),    (3,5),    (3,6)$

$(4,4),    (4,5),    (4,6)$

$(5,5),    (5,6)$

$(6,6)$

Throwing two regular dice, the maximum number of combinations is 21 and no more.

See the combinations above.